# How make a position from data array?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have this sheet on Excel :

```
Team    Total Points    Position
AJPPR   371,1878896 
APP64   261,2121588 
Hold'Emeraude Poker 161,0884561 
Pokertarentaise 28,04744121 
Versailles Texas Hold'em    -6,813862426    
Paname Poker Club   -51,28571092    
Haillan Poker Tour  -29,39344596    
Poker Club de l'Ouest   -45,63838176    
Pok du Rhône    -147,7366997    
Normandie Poker Tour    969,4956105
```

I would like, from the column "Total Points", calculate the rank of each team.

For example : Normandie Poker Tour must have 1 in the column "Position" because it has the biggest value in column "Total Points". "Pok du Rhône" must have 10 in the column "Position" because it has the worst value in column "Total Points".

Anyone has an idea without macro ?

Thanks a lot.

PS : Maybe someone has a idea of a formula with a dynamic number of theam, for example with 12 teams or 20 teams....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the first Cell of position (C2), type in this formula:

```
=RANG($B2;B:B)
```

Then scroll down to apply the formula to the other cells of column "C".

Comment: (I figured your Excel would be in French)... use "RANK" if it's in english.

Answer (score 0):

In the cell C2, try

```
=1+SUMPRODUCT(--($B$2:$B$11>B2))
```

Scroll down and apply to the other cells of C Column